# Creating a TextView for the first 46 Fibonacci numbers on Android

Tags: android, textview, fibonacci

I have this so far, and the result is a blank screen.  What might I do to achieve the desired effect of listing the first 46 Fibonacci numbers?

```
TextView fibNum;
static int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
    public static int fib(int n) {
                int prev1=0, prev2=1;
                for( i=0; i<n; i++) {
                    int savePrev1 = prev1;
                    prev1 = prev2;
                    prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
                }
                return prev1;
    }
    public void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0; i<=46; i++)

        fibNum = new TextView(this);
        fibNum.setText(String.valueOf(fib(i)+", "));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling your 'main' method. Programming Android apps is different than the plain java you might know. The main method will not get called at first. Also you are not adding the TextView to your layout

Comment: 2 things, android doesn't uses main() function to start, you can put the code of main() at the end of onCreate. Second, you need to add the TextView you created to the layout for it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just creating a `TextView` doesn't make it part of the view hierarchy being displayed. Second, Android will never call your `main` method. Third, I don't see how your code even compiles; the loop inside `main` only covers the assignment to `fibNum`, so at the call to `setText`, the variable `i` is not even in scope.

Putting all that aside, let's assume your `activity_main.xml` layout file already has a `TextView` in it with id `@+id/text` where you want to display the numbers. I suggest something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(getFib(46));
}

public static int fib(int n) {
    int prev1 = 0, prev2 = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int savePrev1 = prev1;
        prev1 = prev2;
        prev2 = savePrev1 + prev2;
    }
    return prev1;
}

public static String getFib(int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fib(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(fib(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This assumes that calculating 46 Fibonacci numbers doesn't take an inordinate amount of time. If it does, you'll have to move the calculation to a worker thread (probably easiest to do using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)).

Comment: @GrisHu - I've rolled back your edit. The original order of those statements is proper because `sb` already contains the text for `fib(0)` before the loop is entered. Your edit would result in the first two numbers being concatenated without a delimiter and would also place an extra delimiter at the end of the sequence.